# Why does calling a method not require an import of the class?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, reference, java-stream

Something peculiar I stumbled upon the other day.

Consider the following code (it collects the distinct word length counts of the given `String`s, but that's not important):

```
static void collectByLambda(Collection<String> list) {
    Collection<Integer> collected = list.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(String::length),
            m -> m.keySet()
    ));
}
```

and its equivalent method reference version:

```
static void collectByMethodReference(Collection<String> list) {
    Collection<Integer> collected = list.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(String::length),
            Map::keySet
    ));
}
```

The first (lambda) version does not require you to `import java.util.Map` to compile, the second one does.

Why is this exactly? I can imagine it's because the second version needs to have access to the `Map` class at compile time to build the reference; but how does it know that `Map#keySet()` even exists if it doesn't import `Map`?

Comment: imo calling a method of an object does not require the import of the class, but referencing the class itself does; traditionally i can't think of a place where one would happen without the other ;can't back it up yet though

Comment: @RakeshGR That's basically what the question states. The question is why?

Comment: because it's clear which `keySet` method to invoke in the first example. The one on `m`. Which itself is known due to type inference and so on.

Comment: @ohlec because it's not needed to identify the function when the object itself if available; like zapl says

Comment: It's not peculiar. Java has never required you to use import statements to use a class. This has nothing to do with lambdas. You can write absolutely *any* Java program with no import statements whatsoever, if the type is otherwise made clear, which it is here by the return type of the `groupingBy` call.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that `import` is only a means to allow you using unqualified class-names in your code, nothing more.

Since the first example never explicitly mentions the class name `Map` there is no need to allow for the abbreviated notation, while the second example does mention it. Note that the second example will work without the import when using the fully qualified name:

```
static void collectByMethodReference(Collection<String> list) {
    Collection<Integer> collected = list.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(String::length),
            java.util.Map::keySet
    ));
}
```